# How to increase test coverage using junit and Eclemma?

Tags: java, junit, eclemma

I have a simple class:

```
public class NPP {

    // inputs
    public int m__water_pressure = 0;
    public boolean m__blockage_button = false;
    public boolean m__reset_button = false;

    public int old_m__pressure_mode = 0;
    public boolean old_m__reset_button = false;
    public boolean old_m__blockage_button = false;
    public int old_m__water_pressure = 0;

    // outputs
    public int c__pressure_mode = 0;
    public boolean c__the_overriden_mode = false;
    public int c__the_safety_injection_mode = 0;

    public int p__pressure_mode = 0;
    public boolean p__the_overriden_mode = false;
    public int p__the_safety_injection_mode = 0;    

    public void method__c__pressure_mode() {
        if ( m__water_pressure >= 9 && old_m__water_pressure < 9 && c__pressure_mode == 0 ) {
            p__pressure_mode = 1;
        } else if ( m__water_pressure >= 10 && old_m__water_pressure < 10 && c__pressure_mode == 1 ) {
            p__pressure_mode = 2;
        } else if ( m__water_pressure < 9 && old_m__water_pressure >= 9 && c__pressure_mode == 1 ) {
            p__pressure_mode = 0;
        } else if ( m__water_pressure < 10 && old_m__water_pressure >= 10 && c__pressure_mode == 2 ) {
            p__pressure_mode = 1;
        }
    }

    public void method__c__the_overriden_mode() {
        if ( m__blockage_button == true && old_m__blockage_button == false && m__reset_button == false && !(c__pressure_mode==2) ) {
            p__the_overriden_mode = true;
        } else if ( m__reset_button == true && old_m__reset_button == false && !(c__pressure_mode==2) ) {
            p__the_overriden_mode = false;
        } else if ( c__pressure_mode==2 && !(old_m__pressure_mode==2) ) {
            p__the_overriden_mode = false;
        } else if ( !(c__pressure_mode==2) && old_m__pressure_mode==2 ) {
            p__the_overriden_mode = false;
        }
    }

    public void method__c__the_safety_injection_mode() {
        if ( c__pressure_mode == 0 && c__the_overriden_mode == true ) {
            p__the_safety_injection_mode = 0;
        } else if ( c__pressure_mode == 0 && c__the_overriden_mode == false ) {
            p__the_safety_injection_mode = 1;
        } else if ( c__pressure_mode == 1 || c__pressure_mode == 2 ) {
            p__the_safety_injection_mode = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

And i've wrote this junit class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;


public class NPPTest {

    @Test
    public void testMethod__c__pressure_mode() {
        NPP npp = new NPP();
        npp.m__water_pressure  = 3;
        npp.old_m__water_pressure = 5;
        npp.c__pressure_mode = 2;
        npp.method__c__pressure_mode();
        assertEquals(1, npp.p__pressure_mode);          
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod__c__the_overriden_mode() {
        NPP npp = new NPP();
        npp.m__blockage_button = false;
        npp.old_m__blockage_button = true;
        npp.m__reset_button = false;
        npp.method__c__the_overriden_mode();
        assertFalse(npp.p__the_overriden_mode);

    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod__c__the_safety_injection_mode() {
        NPP npp = new NPP();
        npp.c__pressure_mode = 2;
        npp.c__the_overriden_mode = false;
        npp.method__c__the_safety_injection_mode();
        assertEquals(1, npp.p__the_safety_injection_mode);

    }

}
```

I've been asked to write some tests and to cover 100% of code coverage. But what exactly does it mean? How can i achieve this? I've ran Eclemma and i've got only 46%.

Answer (score 3):

*100% code coverage* means that every line of code is covered by a test.

In other words, your test code should call and go through everything that has been written and make sure it works as expected.

In your case, it means that all the methods must be called and every if-else if case must be tested.

---

Even though *100% code coverage* is very sexy, what matters most is the quality of your test suite.

*85% code coverage* might be near perfect if all the *15%* left is some getters/setters, call to external APIs that is useless to check, glue code that is very very difficult to test and so on. It is up to you to realize what code can and should be tested and what code can be left without knowing that you are leaving holes (and bombs?) in your app.

Comment: So, how should i write my tests? In every test method i should put assertEquals or assertFalse for every possible result?